# Discord.js No respond

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I made a bot using Discord.js but today, I found my bot not working at all. I tried to turn my bot on, but it just doesn't work. I also tried regenerating my discord bot token, but that still doesn't work. The only thing that works is the token on a completely different application. I only replaced my token, but this app works, but this app doesn't work. You may say that I can just make a new application, but I can't because I've already got my bot verified on a 3rd party website and I really wanna figure out what's happening. Here's my code that just does not respond at all.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()
const token = 'Token value'
client.login(token)
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('login success')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that your bot was temporarily banned by discord due to rate limiting. If there was some kind of infinite loop glitch or something where your bot started scraping the same messages over and over again or messaging constantly then it could be temporarily shut down. I would advise you contact support